# Selecting/highlighting text in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

I need to simulate selecting part of the text by mouse. Like on image.

[image: Text selection by mouse]

I tried to use

`moveToElement('xpath', 'selector', 0, 0); // move to start of the element  mouseButtonDown(); moveToElement('xpath', 'selector', 100, 0); // move to the end of the element mouseButtonUp();`

But it is not working. I'm using proper selector (no error in this part, also I can use that selector in developer tools to find proper element)

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.moveToElement('xpath', 'selector', 0, 0)
  .mouseButtonDown(0)
  .moveToElement('xpath', 'selector', 100, 0)
  .mouseButtonUp(0);
```

Here, moveToElement() is used to move the mouse cursor to the start and end of the element, and mouseButtonDown() and mouseButtonUp() are used to simulate the mouse button press and release actions. The 0 parameter in mouseButtonDown() and mouseButtonUp() indicates the left mouse button.

Make sure to replace 'xpath' and 'selector' with the appropriate values for your element. Also, ensure that the element is visible and clickable before attempting to simulate the mouse actions.